# Installing PhoneGap 3rd party plugins

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've recently started playing around with Phonegap 3.3.0.

I found a plugin for phonegap on github that I would like to have as part of my project. I've downloaded the zip from github - but what next? I can I install third party plugins downloaded from the internet?

BTW - don't know if it's relevant, but it's a plugin for IOS.

Comment: May I know which plugins you are trying to install??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to download the plugin.

You should use the command `phonegap local plugin add` followed by the URL of the plugin git. (or `cordova plugin add` if you're using the cordova cli)

Please note that the plugin must contain a plugin.xml file to be compatible with phone gap 3.

Comment: well. i agree with QuickFix that if you have plugin developed for phonegap is much easier to use it. this does not have to limit you developer82. recently i had to develop aphonegap app that read incoming sms as a verification procedure and did not found anything developed for the phonegap to work for me. so following the rules of developing plugin for phonegap i managed to make small java code to work ad normal phonegap plugin.